# The term 'Get-SPBusinessDataCatalogThrottleConfig-Scope' is not recognized as t he name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, bcs

If you are working with a larger external list (more than 2000 items) in dev environment it works perfectly, but when you work in production environment, it throws error

> Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator. Correlation ID: ............

So start to working to fix the BCS limit through powershell.
When I enter below command in powershell I get error in cmd. Any idea?

```
PS C:\Users\Test> Get-SPBusinessDataCatalogThrottleConfig-Scope Throttle
    Type Items Database-GUID-ServiceApplicationProxy 49873fe2-eb81-41da-9e3e-ffc42e
    ce511
    The term 'Get-SPBusinessDataCatalogThrottleConfig-Scope' is not recognized as t
    he name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spel
    ling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct an
    d try again.
    At line:1 char:46
    + Get-SPBusinessDataCatalogThrottleConfig-Scope <<<<  ThrottleType Items Databa
    se-GUID-ServiceApplicationProxy 49873fe2-eb81-41da-9e3e-ffc42ebce511
        + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-SPBusinessD...tleConfig-Sco
       pe:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a blank:

```
Get-SPBusinessDataCatalogThrottleConfig-Scope
```

should be

```
Get-SPBusinessDataCatalogThrottleConfig -Scope
```

also you need to use on of `Global, Database, WebService, Wcf, Custom.` for the scope parameter.

Please see the TechNet documentation here that includes one example:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607904(v=office.15).aspx